# iPhone app bind with ad hoc certificate for specific device no working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, ad-hoc-distribution

We have an iPhone + appleOS only app which is being distributed using an ad-hoc certificate.  This ad hoc certificate includes specific set of UDID that is only for either iPhone or apple watch.

This normally means this IPA can only be installed in those specific UDID devices. But the problem this IPA can also be installed in on other devices which are not provisioned in ad hoc. More specifically these devices are iPad that are registered for use in development in apple developer portal but not provisioned for my app.

So I would like to know why ad-hoc distribution is not working as expected. More specifically Install on designated devices are not working.

Comment: did you look into this provisoning profile and didnt find this devices? can you provide any proof that udid is not there?

Comment: are your sure you havenot made any enterprise provisioning profile?

Comment: I have checked in the embedded.mobileprovision  that is include in ipa.